# Ruby find combination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to take input as a string.

Then I need to find all the possible combination and distinct combination but I am unable to do so.

```
input = "aabb"
```

Output I need to print all Combination =

```
'a','a','b','b','aa','ab','bb','aab','abb','aabb'
```

Now  Distinct combination

```
'a','b','aa','ab','bb','aab','abb','aabb'
```

Then I need to count the letters and do a summation

```
'a','a','b','b','aa','ab','bb','aab','abb','aabb'
```

For this

```
result = 1+1+1+1+2+2+2+3+3+4
```

Similarly  for the other combination I need to find summation.

Comment: If you want to receive any input, please show us what have you already tried.

Comment: okay i am showing you my code

Comment: updated my question please see

Comment: This is merely a code for getting user input, it is not even close to setting up the solution. This looks more like a "coding challenge" that you have run into, and now you are looking for a whole solution to the problem. Also, please don't post `I will post` - `I have posted` comments, it is spamming the comments

Comment: this is not a coding challenge question i was reading in my book but i was unable to solve the problem thats why i posted over here if you can help me in solving the problem so please Do

Comment: Ok, but why have you accepted `edit suggestion` that removes your code of what you have done so far?

Comment: it was by mistake i didn't read the entire change made in edit

Comment: You need to (edit to) enclose all your strings in (single or double) quotes: `"aabb"`, `"a","b",...`. Leaving it as is will surely attract downvotes. Interesting question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland- I have enclose the string with quotes and thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination).

To get all combinations:

```
input = "aabb"
res = []
input.size.times { |n| res << input.chars.combination(n+1).map { |a| a.join } }
res.flatten
#=> ["a", "a", "b", "b", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ab", "ab", "bb", "aab", "aab", "abb", "abb", "aabb"]
```

distinct combinations:

```
res.flatten.uniq 
#=> ["a", "b", "aa", "ab", "bb", "aab", "abb", "aabb"]
```

to count the letters and do a summation:

```
res.flatten.uniq.map(&:size)
#=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
res.flatten.uniq.map(&:size).reduce(:+)
# => 18
```

Comment: Your distinct combination is coming right but the first combination is not coming right

Comment: By using `flat_map` you can avoid the need to `flatten`.

Comment: The first snippet is also generating "non-cnontiguous combinations" which are not wanted here, I think. `"aabb"` is a bad example here, I guess. Lets look at `"1234"`. The result would contain the string `"124"` for example.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the substrings of your `input` (or more generally to get all subsequences of an `Enumerable`) you can use something like this:

```
def subsequences(e)
  a = e.to_a
  indices = (0..a.length - 1).to_a
  indices.product(indices)
    .reject { |i, j| i > j }
    .map { |i, j| a[i..j] }
end
```

You would use that on your string like this: `subsequences(input.chars).map(&:join)`. The `chars` and `join` are only necessary because `String`s are not `Enumerable`, but the `subsequences` function does not really need that. You can just take out the first line and it should still work for strings (anything that has a "slicing" subscript operator, really ...).

Note also that this is not the only way to do this. The basic problem here is to iterate over all ordered pairs of indices of a sequence. You could also do that with basic loops. I just happen to find the cartesian product method very elegant. ;)

Once you have your first list in a variable, say `list`, the second task is as easy as `list.uniq`, and the third one is solved by

```
list.map(&:size).reduce(:+)
```

Comment: As I wrote: For your use case it would be `input.chars`. In general it can be anything having `Enumerable` mixed in. The simplest example is `Array`s, but also `Hash`es, although I don't think that this is all that useful for a `Hash`. ;) (Actually it is even more general, Ruby being a dynamically typed language: `e` can be anything that has a `to_a` method returning something that has a subscript operator that can deal with ranges.)